# How to debug Arduino using Atmel studio?

Tags: arduino-yun, debugging, atmel

I have an Arduino Yun board and an Atmel ICE programmer/debugger. There are 6 pins on the Arduino Yun to connect to Atmel ICE for programming only, but I can't find the pins for debugging. Anyway to do so? Which pins on the Arduino should I connect to Atmel ICE?

Comment: Use the same pins.

Comment: https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/atmega32u4-jtag-debug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Atmel Studio 7 to program Arduino Uno](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405462/using-atmel-studio-7-to-program-arduino-uno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another very easy way to debug the arduino board with atmel studio without even using an external debugeer like the atmel ice debugger. It's an extension called vMicro which can be added within atmel studio (visual studio as well) you connect the arduino board over the micro USB to the computer and specify the parameters in the vMicro toolbar in atmel studio and that's it!
 It's ready to debug! Finally I think atmel ice is thought for other boards maybe, since debugging can be done without it easily!